# How do I include the id of a Jquery UI Tab in the url?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have three tabs on a page called `Main.aspx`.  I want it so that when the user first accesses `Main.aspx`, the url changes to the default tab and when a different tab is clicked, the url changes to refer to the id of that tab.  So for example, if they click `Second Tab`, I want the url to be `Main.aspx#secondTab`.  That way, if they refresh the page, it will remain on the current tab.

How would I accomplish this?

```
<div id="everyNavigationTabID" class="everyNavigationTabClass">
 <ul class="singleTabNavigationClass">
                <li><a href="#firstTab">First Tab</a></li>
                <li><a href="#secondTab">Second Tab</a></li>
                <li><a href="#thirdTab">Third Tab</a></li>
            </ul>    
<div id="firstTab" class="tabContent">
                First Tab
 </div>
 <div id="secondTab" class="tabContent">
                Second Tab
 </div>
 <div id="thirdTab" class="tabContent">
                Third Tab
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `document.location.hash` property to add `#` fragments to your current URL.

Something like -

```
$("div.tabContent").on('click',function(evt){
   document.location.href = document.location.href + "#" + $(this).attr('id');
   evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Then on your `$(function()` (document.ready) function you can examine the `document.location.hash` variable and take appropriate actions.

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but why is the `return false` included?

Comment: @Chris to stop the click from happening and bubbling up. `preventDefault` is the preferred means of doing this now.

Comment: Fantastic question.  I always like my functions to return something - even if it is just a dummy false value.  A good use for placing a `return false` in a function like this would be if the elements the user was clicking were `<a>` tags with an `href` attribute - when a user clicks on a link like that the page will sometimes scroll to the top - return false prevents that behavior.  I used it becuase I am used to it :)

Comment: @vcs - thanks for that.  Indeed a move verbose and explanatory method.